# How can I plot more regression trend line in the same graph?

Tags: plotting, fitting

I would like to do something like the example I drawed manually:

```
data = MapAt[DateString[{#, {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}}] &,
  Import["D:\\Analytics www.superinformati.com Panoramica del pubblico 20141201-20150303 - Sheet 1.tsv"][[3 ;;, {1, 2}]]
 , {All, 1}]

tsm = TimeSeriesModelFit[data]

DateListPlot[{tsm["TemporalData"]}]
```

[image]

The series of data is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dmv_C2_J7uG8zIhxe5aYZbg79MREI8ePsFJTStSKEeE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: It's probably best to merge this question [with your other one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82903/7167) since they are very related.

Comment: @bobthechemist: the set of data is the same, but you have already answered this pretty well. As you prefer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be useful..

```
 sampledata =
      {#, 
      Piecewise[ {{ 1 + # , # < 1}  , { 6 (# - 1) + 2 , # > 1} }]
      (1 + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, .2]])} & 
         /@ RandomReal[{0, 2}, 50];


 Manipulate[
     fit = NonlinearModelFit[ sampledata , 
       Piecewise[ {{ a + b  x , x <= m }  ,
                 { c (x - m) + a + b m , x > m} }] , {a, b, c} , x];
     Show[{ListPlot[sampledata, Epilog -> Inset[Grid[{{
         "R^2=" <> ToString[fit["RSquared"]], "m=" <> ToString[m]},
          fit["BestFitParameters"]}], Scaled[{.4, .75}]]],
       Plot[fit@x, {x, 0, m}, PlotStyle -> Red],
       Plot[fit@x, {x, m, 2}, PlotStyle -> Blue]}], {{m, 1}, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

For this simple case it works well if you also make the transition point a fit parameter:

```
 Clear[m];
 fit = NonlinearModelFit[ sampledata , 
     Piecewise[ {{ a + b  x , x <= m }  , 
                { c (x - m) + a + b m , x > m} 
               }] ,  {a, b, c, m} , x];
 x0 = m /. fit["BestFitParameters"];
 Show[{ListPlot[sampledata],
     Plot[fit@x, {x, 0, x0}, PlotStyle -> Red],
     Plot[fit@x, {x, x0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Blue]}]
```

In general you are likely better off doing that by hand though